# Rails: Generate a Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm trying to find a way to get this done:

-> Every time when a "Sale" gets saved to the DB rails has to generate a hash (not longer than 250 characters) and save the value to the column "token".

I've searched a lot but nothing met my requirements. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Explain your requirements more clearly

Comment: Did you look at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html

Comment: @RORDeveloper the rest got it :) Sorry if it was not clear enough. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of richfisher answer:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :generate_token
  validates :token, uniqueness: true
  def generate_token(length=50)
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length, false)
  end
end
```

uniqueness can be ensured through a [validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness).

**Edit**
The validation above is useless and doesn't solve the problem when the generated token is not unique. A loop is needed (like what joshua.paling proposed), or better use `has_secure_token` (proposed by Mike Desjardins) which [implements](https://github.com/robertomiranda/rails/commit/5a58ba3366ec6092fcd0e69340acd93f347d2576) something similar. On top you’re encouraged to add a unique index in the database to avoid race conditions:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_token
  def generate_token(length=50)
    loop do
      token = self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length, false)
      break token unless self.class.exists?(token: token)
    end
  end
end
```

Edited "validates"

Comment: one additional question: How can I make sure that this token only gets saved once it in the DB? Because at this moment the hash gets recreated every time I update a "Sale". Thank you!

Comment: just assign only if not 'nil' by doing: self.token ||= SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length, false)

Comment: This is incorrect. Uniqueness cannot be ensured through validation in this context. Validation is for validating user input. If you asked the user to input their own random token, then validation would be suitable for giving them a message saying "sorry, that token isn't unique, try another one".

Comment: But in this context, when we are automatically generating the token server-side, what would we do if the validation fails? Send the user a message saying "sorry, the token our code tried to generate for you was not uniqe"? No. You want to just try again until you get a token that's unique - as per my answer.

Comment: I agree, and this is actually how 'has_secure_token' is implemented in Rails 5. I've changed the above solution to correct this. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

My go-to for this kinda thing is `SecureRandom.hex`. It takes a parameter indicating length - eg. `SecureRandom.hex(250)` in your case. It's hex - so uses digits, then the letters a-f.

And I imagine you also want it to be unique amongst all records in your database? If so, you'll want something like this in your model:

```
def generate_unique_token
  loop do
    token = SecureRandom.hex
    break token unless self.class.exists?(token: token)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @joshua.paling , I get the following error:
   undefined method `exists?' for SalesController:Class

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Harakiri: "in your model"

Comment: Yep, put the code in your model, not in your controller. And, be sure to add a unique index on your token at the database level, too.

Comment: @joshua.paling I've put the following in my model and modified SecureRandom to "SecureRandom.hex(250)". No errors anymore. But nothing gets saved. Shouldn't there be a method to save the value to the DB?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to everyone else's answer... Rails 5 has a `has_secure_token` method that you can simply add to your ActiveRecord class, e.g.,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_token
end
```

This method basically does the dirty work that everyone else is suggesting you do.  If you're not on Rails 5 yet, there's a Rails 4 backport available:

https://github.com/robertomiranda/has_secure_token

Comment: I think Rails 5 isn't officially released yet, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, Rails 5 still edge, which is why I included the Rails 4 backport. I honestly don't know many people using Rails 5 yet. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :generate_token
  def generate_token(length=250)
    self.token = [*('A'..'Z'),*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].sample(length).join
  end
end
```

you can control the length and character.

Comment: This is a good answer. It is just missing: "validate :token, uniqueness: true" in order to ensure uniqueness. And instead of a custom function to generate the token, you can use SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length, false)

Comment: Hi @Mapad How would it look like in complete?